# How to access https page via wget or curl?

Tags: unix, ssl, curl, wget

Let's say I want to save the contents of my Facebook page. Obviously fb uses https, thus ssl, how do I download the contents of a secure page using wget?

I found a lot of sources online... and I modify my command, but it doesn't save the page I want.

```
wget --secure-protocol=auto "https://www.facebook.com/USERNAMEHERE" -O index.html
```

Actually this is the result I'm getting in index.html:
"Update Your Browser
You’re using a web browser that isn’t supported by Facebook.
To get a better experience, go to one of these sites and get the latest version of your preferred browser:"

Comment: http://linuxfreelancer.com/modifying-user-agent-in-curl-or-wget

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not the SSL / https. The problem is the fact that facebook sees "wget" as the agent and tells "update your browser".

You have to fool facebook with the --user-agent switch and imitate a modern browser.

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" https://facebook.com/USERNAME -O index.html
```

and then you will see the actual facebook page if you open index.html in a modern browser.

Comment: what is the purpose of "‘--secure-protocol=protocol’" flag then?

Comment: As the man page says, using --secure-protocol you can specify which protocol (say tls1, tls2, ssl, ..) you want to use. Giving it "auto" lets the wget to choose the protocol by itself but you can also specify the one you want manually.